# Creating Scheduled Start date column

Tags: powerbi

How to write DAX for the following scenario?

[image]

I want to create a Scheduled start date column. When the Start date is available Scheduled start date = Start date. Ex - Order Number 123, the Scheduled Start date is 20/03/2021. If the start date is blank scheduled start date is the start of the parent order number. Ex Start date of Order no 124 is blank. Therefore start date of order 124 is 15/02/2021 which is the start date of parent order 122 (The Parent order of order124).

Answer (score 0):

```
calculatedColumn =
SWITCH (
    TRUE (),
    ISBLANK ( 'Table'[start] ) = TRUE (),
        MAXX (
            FILTER ( 'Table', 'Table'[order#] = MAX ( 'Table'[parent#] ) ),
            'Table'[start]
        ),
    'Table'[start]
)
```

[image: calculatedColumn]